# why asp.net Url rewriting throw exception when same folder is exists physicaly?

Tags: url-rewriting

Im redirect like this:
rewrite url="~/aboutus/" to="~/AboutUs/AboutUsView.aspx"

but "AboutUs" folder physically exists. so IIS throw exception:

Directory Listing -- /WebSite/aboutus/

but this rewritin work good:
rewrite url="~/about/" to="~/AboutUs/AboutUsView.aspx"

"About" folder is not exist physically.

im using Intelligencia.UrlRewriter.dll

plz help me!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like IIS is intercepting the request before it can get to your URL rewriter.  Because the physical folder exists it will try to list the directory contents if enabled, or load the default document (default.aspx, default.htm, etc.)

If IIS can't do either of these things, then it'll throw an error and stop processing the request, it won't ever reach your ISAPI rewriter filter.

Can you change the physical folder names to get around this?

Comment: is there any solotion without folder renaming?